# Button is pushed down inside div when input box is %100 width

Tags: html, css

It appears that my button is being pushed down inside my div when I ask the input text box to fill the rest of the width inside my div. How can I get the button neatly beside my input while trying to use the input to fill the remaining width of my div?

I have attached a quick pic of the problem (left) and the desired result on the (right):

[image]

Here is the HTML Markup:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 200px;">
      <input type="text" style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; border: 0;"><input type="button" value="x"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: _“when I ask the input text box to fill the rest of the width”_ – that’s not what you are doing. `100%` does not mean “rest”, it means 100%. // Flexbox solves stuff like this beautifully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to go about fixing this. But one way is with flexbox.
Add `display: flex;` to your outer div.

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 200px; display: flex;">
        <input type="text" style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; border: 0;"><input type="button" value="x">
    </div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vqctrd2z/)

Answer (score 0):

It is not very flexible, but it works

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 200px;">
      <input type="text" style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 175px; border: 0;"><input type="button" value="x" style="width:25px"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```